# Alloy 5.0 (includes the version for macOS High Sierra)

Tags: alloy

How to install under windows platform for alloy5.0.

When I execute:

```
java -jar Alloy-5.0.0.1.jar
```

In the windows command line, I get the error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: edu/mit/csail/sdg/alloy4whole/SimpleGUI : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 has appeared.

I hope someone will give an installation method

Comment: I’ve just [edited your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing), improving either its formatting, or [its quality](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/02/05/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/) to help people understanding your question, and to help you to get an appropriate answer.
But you still need to add further information for your question to become solvable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need a newer Java VM. Alloy 5 is compiled with Java 8.